# Redirect from mypage.domain to mypage.domain/page with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

as the title says I would like to redirect from:
**mypage.domain** to **mypage.domain/page**

I already tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 / http://www.mypage.domain/page
```

And I get an error that the page isn't redirecting properly, and also the url points to something like:

```
www.mypage.domain/pagepagepagepagepagepagepagepage
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may not want to do it in php, but I always have trouble doing it with htaccess, so it's just a suggestion.
index.php file: header('Location: http\://www.mypage.domain/page');
The forward slash after http is just to prevent it from being a link in this comment. So ignore it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that. I've my page on a hosting and if I enter with mypage.domain I get the page of "Index of /". And in the ftp the only files that I have are public_html > .htacces, myWebsiteFolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. 301 status code is used for permanent redirect and here you are redirecting it to the same domain again. So when the first redirect happens, it again comes to mypage.domain and then again the .htaccess file is consulted and again a redirect happens.
Hence in a way it goes into a loop.

A proper 301 redirect should be done in the following way:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mynewpage.domain/
```

What you need here is to redirect the landing page to a specific sub folder in the root directory. Something of the following sort would work for you:

```
Redirect /index.html http://mypage.domain/page/
```

Here the index.html can be your any landing page. It can be index.php etc.

Comment: As I said in other reply, when I enter in mypage.domain I get the page of "Index of /" so I have no idea how can I redirect from there to mypage.domain/page/. Also I'm using CodeIgniter, dunno if this changes something, but anyway I'm not using the internal .htacess from CodeIgniter.

Comment: All you have to do is to create a .htaccess file in your root location "/" and the copy paste the above given code. I just tested the same and it works. You do not even need to create and index.html file

Comment: WOW. Awesome man, I didn't know that I dont need even an index.html. Thank you very much, worked 100%!